# simple String example

Tags: java, string

i have the following piece of code but i could not detect why there is no output 
when i debug it , the control flow is never goes inside for loop but i cannot figure out why

could anyone please help me ?
 here is my code

```
public class DealWithStrings {
    ArrayList<String> container = new ArrayList<>();

    public void printDuplicate() {
        String string = "aaabed";
        String[] res = string.split("");

        for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
            if (res[i] == res[i - 1]) {
                container.add(res[i]);
            }
        }

        for (String s : container) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DealWithStrings d = new DealWithStrings();
        d.printDuplicate();
    }
}
```

Comment: it does go into the loop, the `if` never eveluates to `true` though

Answer (score 3):

Compare String using `.equals`, not `==`

Instead of

```
if(res[i]==res[i-1])
```

Use

```
if(res[i].equals(res[i-1]))
```

`==` will evaluate to true if the objects are the same, and in this case they never are. `.equals` will check if the contents of the Strings (the actual text) are the same.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Yes, why the downvote? Stack Overflow is so weird.

Comment: I´m not the one downvoting but it might be the case [that we shouldn´t answer on clear duplicates (answer well-asked questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How helpful to punish someone with a negative number for that.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your code '==' operator with '.equals()' method, because , 
'==' equal operator compares the reference of the two characters in memory, whereas you need to check 'contents' at that reference.

And .equals method  is overridden to check the content for Strings.

```
for (int i = 1; i < string.length(); i++) {
        if (res[i].equals(res[i - 1])) {
            container.add(res[i]);
        }
    }
```